# syslog-ng prepending date to received logs, breaking patterns in patterndb

Tags: syslog, syslog-ng, pattern-matching

I'm setting up central logging for our servers using `syslog-ng` + `patterndb`, however the logs the logging server is receiving from the client are prepended with the date, host and other data. This of course breaks all the patterns in `patterndb` so nothing matches.

Is there a way to do some preprocessing on the source log file before attempting to classify it or some other way to overcome this problem?

Cheers.

Relevant client conf:

```
source s_src {
   system();
   internal();
};

destination d_central_logging {
    syslog(192.168.1.1 transport("tcp") port("12345")); 
};

log {
    source(s_src);
    destination(d_central_logging);
};
```

Relevant server conf:

```
parser p_patterndb {
    db-parser(file("/var/lib/syslog-ng/patterndb.xml"));
};

source s_network {
    tcp(port(12345) flags(syslog-protocol));
};

filter f_class_unknown {
    match("unknown"
        value(".classifier.class")
        type("string")
    );
};

destination d_all {
    file("/tmp/all");
};

destination d_unknown {
    file("/tmp/unknown");
};

log {
    source(s_network);
    parser(p_patterndb);
    log {
        filter(f_class_unknown);
        destination(d_unknown);
    };
    log {
        destination(d_all);
    };
};
```

EDIT:

original log line:
`10.0.2.2 - - [23/Dec/2014:13:42:49 +0000] "GET /assets/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36"`

modified log line:
`Dec 23 13:59:08 192.168.33.44 264 <13>1 2014-12-23T13:42:50+00:00 devhost 10.0.2.2 - - [meta sequenceId="8"] - - [23/Dec/2014:13:42:49 +0000] "GET /assets/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36"`

Comment: Shouldn't the source clause on the server use syslog() rather than tcp()?

Comment: ah nuts - I was switching between different versions to see which worked best. Fwiw, I've settled on this one: `syslog(ip(192.168.1.1) port("12345")); ` - I'll re-run patterndb over the new output (which is less mangled but still prefixed) and update with what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I've found the real reason why a match wasn't being made. I was using the `update-patterndb` command after confirming that the correct Apache patterns existed in the `github.com/balabit/syslog-ng-patterndb` repo. However, the `update-patterndb` command wasn't including `.xml` files, only `.pdb` files. I saw the compiled pattern file at `/var/lib/syslog-ng/patterndb.xml` changing but never checked it. As the man pages for `update-patterndb` say, it's only a thin wrapper around the `pdbtool merge` command. This works for me:

```
pdbtool merge -r --glob *.xml -D /etc/syslog-ng/patterndb.d/syslog-ng-patterndb/
```

The directory `/etc/syslog-ng/patterndb.d/syslog-ng-patterndb/` is where I have the repo cloned.
I can confirm the Apache patterns are now extracting the content as expected by inspecting the compiled pattern file, running the `pdbtool test` command and seeing the structured results in those that receive the data downstream.

Answer (score 0):

Paul is right, the protocols used in the client-destination and the server-source are mismatched. As a result, the server does not recognize the incoming message as a properly-formatted syslog message, and prepends the host, date and other information.

Regards,

Robert